# How to make "Return" button to go back to the previous menu in Python Telegram Bot?

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

right now i'm developing my own Telegram Bot to get data from the website.

My Bot is consist of multiple InlineKeyboardButton and handled by ConversationHandlers. So my menu is completely done but i've got some issues here. How to make "return" button so i can move to the previous menu or back to main menu? I dont have any idea how to make it work

Here my code

```
def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    """Send a message when the command /start is issued."""
    user = update.effective_user
    update.message.reply_markdown_v2(
        fr'Hi {user.mention_markdown_v2()}\!',
    )


def main_menu(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    """Send a message when the command /start is issued."""
    
    button = [
        
        [InlineKeyboardButton("Beacon", callback_data='beacon'),
        InlineKeyboardButton("Smartfren", callback_data='smartfren')],
        [InlineKeyboardButton("IBS", callback_data='ibs')]
    ]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(button)
    update.message.reply_text("Selamat datang di BOT NPA, Silahkan pilih menu dibawah ini", reply_markup=reply_markup)
    return menus


def help_command(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    """Send a message when the command /help is issued."""
    update.message.reply_text('Help!')


def menus(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:

    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()
    
    # This will define which button the user tapped on (from what you assigned to "callback_data". As I assigned them "1" and "2"):
    choose = query.data

    if choose == 'beacon':
        button = [
        
            [InlineKeyboardButton("Cikarang", callback_data='beacon_ckr'),
            InlineKeyboardButton("Rawakalong", callback_data='beacon_rk')],
            [InlineKeyboardButton("HK Main", callback_data='beacon_hk1'),
            InlineKeyboardButton("HK Backup", callback_data='beacon_hk2')],
            [InlineKeyboardButton("Back to Main Menu", callback_data='main_menu')]
        
        ]
        reply = InlineKeyboardMarkup(button)
        query.message.edit_text("Silahkan pilih lokasi yang akan dicek", reply_markup=reply)

    if choose == 'smartfren':
        button = [
        
            [InlineKeyboardButton("Summary Smartfren All", callback_data='all_smartfren'),
            InlineKeyboardButton("Onggunoi", callback_data='sf_onggunoi')],
            [InlineKeyboardButton("Muara Intan", callback_data='sf_muaraintan'),
            InlineKeyboardButton("Deceng", callback_data='sf_deceng')],
            [InlineKeyboardButton("Berau", callback_data='sf_berau'),
            InlineKeyboardButton("Backhaul", callback_data='sf_backhaul')],
            [InlineKeyboardButton("Back to Main Menu", )]
        
        ]
        reply = InlineKeyboardMarkup(button)
        query.message.edit_text("Silahkan pilih lokasi yang akan dicek", reply_markup=reply)
#   updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(main_menu, pattern='main_menu')
    #if choose == 'ibs':
    return beacon

def beacon(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()
    
    # This will define which button the user tapped on (from what you assigned to "callback_data". As I assigned them "1" and "2"):
    choose = query.data

    if choose == 'beacon_ckr':
        beacon_ckr = beacon_cikarang()
        query.message.edit_text(beacon_ckr)
    if choose == 'beacon_rk':
        beacon_rk = beacon_rawakalong()
        query.message.edit_text(beacon_rk)
    if choose == 'main_menu':
def main() -> None:
    """Start the bot."""
    # Create the Updater and pass it your bot's token.
    updater = Updater("")

    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

    # on different commands - answer in Telegram
    #updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(button))
    #dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    #dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("main_menu", main_menu))
    """dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", help_command))
    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("beacon", beacon))
    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("smartfren", smartfren))
    
"""
    # on non command i.e message - echo the message on Telegram
    dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, echo))
    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
    entry_points=[CommandHandler("main_menu", main_menu)],
    states={
        menus: [CallbackQueryHandler(menus)],
        beacon : [CallbackQueryHandler(beacon)]

        },
    fallbacks=[CommandHandler('main_menu', main_menu)]
    )

    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(conv_handler)
    
    # Start the Bot
    updater.start_polling()

    # Run the bot until you press Ctrl-C or the process receives SIGINT,
    # SIGTERM or SIGABRT. This should be used most of the time, since
    # start_polling() is non-blocking and will stop the bot gracefully.
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should revoke the Bot token that you posted as part of your code example

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure my approach is the correct one, but in your case I will resolve the issue in this way.

I tried to restructure your code adding the possibility to switch between menus, here what I came up with:

```py
def main_menu(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    """Shows the main menu when the command /menu is issued."""

    button = [

        [InlineKeyboardButton("Beacon", callback_data='beacon'),
         InlineKeyboardButton("Smartfren", callback_data='smartfren')],
        [InlineKeyboardButton("IBS", callback_data='ibs')]
    ]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(button)
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,
                             text="Selamat datang di BOT NPA, Silahkan pilih menu dibawah ini",
                             reply_markup=reply_markup)

def sub_menu(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    button = [

        [InlineKeyboardButton("TEST1", callback_data='test1'),# does nothing
         InlineKeyboardButton("TEST2", callback_data='test2')],# does nothing
        [InlineKeyboardButton("BACK", callback_data='back')]
    ]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(button)
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,text="Selamat datang di BOT NPA, Silahkan pilih menu dibawah ini", reply_markup=reply_markup)

def main():

    updater = Updater(token=TOKEN, use_context=True)
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
    # Handles the command /menu and shows the first menu to the user
    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('menu', main_menu))

    # Handles the choice of the user when 'beacon' is selected in the first menu, and shows an hypothetical sub menu
    dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(sub_menu, pattern='beacon'))

    # Handles the choice of the user when 'beacon' is selected in the first menu, and shows an hypothetical sub menu
    dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(sub_menu, pattern='smartfren'))

    # Every time the back button is pressed, the main_menu fucntion is triggered and the user sees the previous menu
    dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(main_menu, pattern='back'))

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

For the sake of simplicity, I defined a `CommandHandler`which executes the `main_menu` function when the user inputs the `/menu` command.

Then, depending on the choice, another `CallbackQueryHandler` shows a second sub menu, whether the user select 'beacon' or 'smartfren' from the main one.

Now, in this second menu there are three buttons, two of them are useless, just for test purposes (*TEST1* and *TEST2*), while the third one is used to come back to the previous menu (*BACK*). This is accomplished inserting a further `CallbackQueryHandler`, which every time the user selects the *BACK* button, it triggers the `main_menu` function showing the previous menu.

Be aware, that now to send messages to the chat, you can't use anymore the `update.message` object, because in the case of a `CallbackQueryHandler` this is `Null`, you have to use `context.bot.send_message` instead.

Hope it helps, for any doubts, ask.